# Does VAR scope in function really get Garbage collected quickly if the reference is shared?

Tags: coldfusion, garbage-collection

if I have a function say

```
<cfcomponent name="details">
<cffunctiion  name="getDetails" access="public" returntype="struct">
<cfscript>
var mydetails = {};
mydetails.fName='lilly';
mydetails.lName ='flower';
</cfscript>
<cfreturn mydetails >
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

now i will call this function and get the return to a session variable

```
<cfset session.mydetails = details.getDetails()>
```

What i get here is a reference of the structure mydetails (since it is a complex object) from the function. I believe the reference will point to the same memory location which it was created when I called the function and the variable was created inside it.

So will that var scope really garbage collected since i have the reference still pointing to the memory location through my new session.myDetails variable!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return the value from the object, it's not returned as a reference. Try this:

## TestComponent.cfc

```
<cfcomponent name="details">

    <cffunction  name="getDetails" access="public" returntype="struct">
        <cfscript>
            var mydetails = {};
            mydetails.fName='lilly';
            mydetails.lName ='flower';
            mydetails.timestamp = GetTickCount();
        </cfscript>

        <cfreturn mydetails />

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

## Test.cfm

```
<cfset myObject = CreateObject("component", "TestComponent") />
<cfset myDetails = myObject.getDetails() />
<cfdump var="#myDetails#" label="First Request" />
<cfset otherDetails = myObject.getDetails() />
<cfdump var="#myDetails#" label="After second request" />
<cfdump var="#otherDetails#" label="otherDetails from second request" />
```

You'll notice that the first and second dumps for myDetails are the same, which means that the second request, where the variable is set to "otherDetails" does not change the original value in "myDetails". This means that the structure was returned, and assigned to the variable, byValue instead of byReference.

With that being said, the original local variable in the component should get garbage collected at the same time as the component instance itself, while the struct sitting in session won't get garbage collected until the session does.

Comment: I think it is more like one (1) object is created in memory and there are multiple references to it: var myDetails and variables.myVariables. The object can be garbage collected only after all of the references are out of scope / object unreachable.

Comment: Correction, that should be variables.`myDetails`. The reason the second request does not effect the original is because the function creates a brand new structure each time. But it still returns a pointer not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

> does the var scope variable
>   (myDetails) is garbage collected
>   immediately when the function call is
>   done! or it will wait untill the last
>   child variable which is still
>   referring to it is removed

If you mean the underlying structure, it is the latter. The first part of the code creates a single structure in memory, but multiple references to that stucture. Nothing is being copied. So the underlying structure will not be *eligible* for garbage collection until the last reference is out of scope / unreachable.

```
 // First Reference 
 var mydetails = {};
```

The first reference goes out of scope when the `cffunction` ends

```
 <cfset variables.myDetails = myObject.getDetails() />
```

Another reference moves out of scope when the `.cfm` script ends

```
 // Last Reference
 session.amKeepingHer = mydetails;
```

The last reference has the longest lifespan. It only goes out of scope when the `session` ends. So getting back to the initial question: the original structure will not eligible for garbage collection until the session ends. The jvm decides when that garbage collection actually occurs.